# Definition of a general rule

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation, rule, semantic-matching

By defining:

```
rule = Sqrt[expr_^2] :> expr;
```

and writing:

```
Sqrt[x^2] /. rule
```

I get:

> x

which is what is desired (regardless of formal correctness).

On the other hand, writing:

```
Sqrt[x^2 y] /. rule
```

I get:

> Sqrt[x^2 y]

instead of:

> x Sqrt[y]

How can I generalize the above rule so that it also applies in the second case?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would generalize, but `Sqrt/@(x^2 y)/.rule` gives the desired output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
rule = Sqrt[a_. * expr_^n_?EvenQ] :> expr^(n/2)*Sqrt[a];

expr = {Sqrt[x^2], Sqrt[x^2 * y], Sqrt[x^2*y^2], Sqrt[x^2*y*z], 
   Sqrt[x^4*y^2 *z]};
```

Using [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) (`/.`)

```
expr /. rule

{x, x Sqrt[y], x Sqrt[y^2], x Sqrt[y z], x^2 Sqrt[y^2 z]}
```

However, in general [`ReplaceRepeated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) (`//.`) is needed

```
expr //. rule

(* {x, x Sqrt[y], x y, x Sqrt[y z], x^2 y Sqrt[z]} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not use [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand):

```
PowerExpand[Sqrt[x^2 y]]
```

> x Sqrt[y]